# Check LED light color & accuracy using Colormunki display probe

Tags: colors, led

Ok, i have a XRite Colormunki display probe which i use to calibrate my screens using dispcal / Argyll. For a DIY film scanner project I'd like to check several neopixel led matrices I am contemplating to use as backlights for color temperature, accuracy and basically get reliable readings for them to fine-tune the RGBW levels accordingly, using an arduino to control them.

I tried to find out if Argyll / Dispcal can be "abused" for this purpose but there doesn't seem to be preference of somebody doing it. Also I couldn't find alternative (open source) software that uses commodity display probes to measure light color accuracy.

Neither could i find programming libraries that are enabling programmaticaly accessing commodity color probes...

Possible that I didn't use the right keywords in my searches, so maybe it is easy to find when knowing what to look for.

[There doesn't seem to be a "Maker" centered stackxchange community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313610/is-there-a-stack-exchange-site-to-ask-maker-type-questions) so i hope it fits here.

So, are there any (open source) softwares, software (python) libraries or other tools that make use of commodity display probes to check the accuracy of light sources other than computer screens? Realtime readout would be great but not mandatory. This could be Windows or Linux, i am using both.

Comment: Software recs are off-topic, but I'd guess you're looking for CRI [colour rendering index] which is in effect a measure of how "flat" lighting is. It measures individual  bands out of 'white' rather than each 'gun' individually. Argyll can do this using 'spotread' - https://www.argyllcms.com/doc/spotread.html or google "measure cri argyll"

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, yes, but thats only one part of it. I can adjust the Neopixel / RGBW LED Matrices to any colors i want, but i have no reference value in WHAT exactly a certain setting in the arduino sketch means in terms of color. So i am trying to figure out with what tools i can establish a certain "baseline" between what the softwares values mean in real life color output....